# javascript replace instance of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all instance of particular string using javascript/jquery.

My source string is '\\n' and my desired output is '\n'.

this should happen at all instance with in a string.

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: my input is "hii All, \\n I am sambo. \\n Thank you for listening."
my main concern is to give break line in alert

Comment: `var s = "hii All, \\\n I am sambo. \\\n Thank you for listening.";alert(s.replace(/\\n/gi, '\n'))`  add `\` in front of the `\n` to match your actual string - eg is that `\` `\` `n` or is it `\` `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "hii All, \\n I am sambo. \\n Thank you for listening.";
var res = str.replace(/\\n/gi, "\n");
console.log(str);
```

Use replace with regex.